# Terraform - access root module script from child module

Tags: gitlab, terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a **ROOT_MODULE** with `main.tf`:

```
#Root Module - Just run the script
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local_exec" {
    command = "./script.sh"
}
```

and `script.sh`:

```
echo "Hello world
```

now I have another directory elsewhere where I've created a **CHILD_MODULE** with another `main.tf`:

```
#Child Module
module "ROOT_MODULE" {
  source = "gitlabURL/ROOT_MODULE"
}
```

I've exported my planfile:  `terraform plan -out="planfile"`
however, when I do `terraform apply` against the planfile, the directory I am currently in no longer has any idea where the script.sh is. I need to keep the script in the same directory as the root module. This script is also inside a gitlab repository so I don't have a local path to call it. *Any idea as to how I can get this script into my child module / execute it from my planfile?*

```
Error running command './script.sh': exit status 1. Output: cannot access 'script.sh': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access the path to the root module config to preserve pathing for files with the `path.root` intrinsic:

```
provisioner "local_exec" {
  command = "${path.root}/script.sh"
}
```

However, based on your question, it appears you have swapped the terminology for root module and child module. Therefore, that module appears to really be your child module and not root, and you need to access the path with the `path.module` intrinsic:

```
provisioner "local_exec" {
  command = "${path.module}/script.sh"
}
```

and then the pathing to the script will be preserved regardless of your current working directory.

These intrinsic expressions are documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/references.html#filesystem-and-workspace-info).

Comment: Agree this is the answer but can you find recent docs for this? Because I could only find 0.11 version docs.

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 They have indeed disappeared explicitly from the documentation, but still exist implicitly. Updating answer.

Comment: I think this is the documentation you are looking for: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/references.html#filesystem-and-workspace-info

Comment: @MartinAtkins Now we have to ping you the next time someone is looking for hidden documentation.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as path.root seems to give a path relative to the parent (e.g. ./path/to or ../path/to). I have to use path.cwd to get a full absolute path which I can then pass to or use in child modules. Not sure if that's expected behaviour..