# How to specify path of the templatefile in terraform

Tags: path, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-step-functions, terraform-template-file

I have a json file which has the definition of a stepfunction statemachine, then in terraform I wanted to use `templatefiile()`, the current folder structure is:

```
terraform folder -> terraform file (e.g: step-function.tf file) & json file (e.g: step-function.json)
```

in step-function.tf file:

```
definition = templatefile("step-function.json",
    {
      xxxxxxx
    }
)
```

This will give me error:

```
Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at
step-function.json; this function works only with files
that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file
will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain
this result from an attribute of that resource.
```

I don't fully understand why, how can I modify this path, when I test this terraform script locally, if I use `templatefile("../../xxx/xxx/terraform/step-function,json")` it will work, but I don't want to use this expression, how can I modify it? Many thanks.

Comment: I suggest providing exact, reproducible code that you use. Otherwise no will know if you have other typos in your question or not.

Comment: @Marcin Hi I think this is a path issue so it doesn't matter what's in the file or the code, I just don't understand how to specify the path for `templatefile()` in Terraform.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151558/terraform-access-root-module-script-from-child-module/65157034#65157034

Comment: @Cecilia Glad that helped. Please upvote the answer if it was useful..